# Heroku NODE_ENV environment variable not being set properly

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I have a couple of apps running on Heroku and it would seem NODE_ENV is always set to `production`, even though I have it manually set to `development` in the environment variables on heroku.

When deploying, I see this in the logs:

```
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_ENV=development
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
```

So it would look like NODE_ENV is being set appropriately, however the app behaves as if it were set to `production`.

Is it possible to override NODE_ENV on heroku?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's the code I'm using.

```
let AUTH_URL = 'https://development.com';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    AUTH_URL = 'https://development.com'
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging') {
    AUTH_URL = 'https://staging.com'
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    AUTH_URL = 'https://production.com'
}

export {
    AUTH_URL
}
```

AUTH_URL is then used in other scripts as the base URL to make API calls to. I have NODE_ENV environment variable set to development, but the URL being set is always `https://production.com` no matter the value of NODE_ENV on heroku. Here's a screenshot of the environment variables set up on heroku

[image]

Comment: "It is not a bug with my code"—that's a bold statement, especially considering you haven't shown us any of your code. What does "however the app behaves as if it were set to `production`" mean, _specifically_? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris I've updated the question.

Comment: @picklechips did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check `package.json` for `start`script. If it has something similar to below it might be overwriting it.

**package.json**

```
{
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js"
  },
...
}
```

So convert it to

```
{
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "node ./server/index.js"
  },
...
}
```